# Algorithm for optimizaiton of discrete and continuous data variables?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, discrete-mathematics

i am currently working on an optimization problem that has both continuous and discrete variable
like 
budget shoud be between 20,000 to 30,000
and methods 1,2,3..
when i use the method 1 the next time i should not be using this somewhat like queuing 
Methods can be used any number of times but not simultaneously.
cost for methods 1,2,3 are 1000,2000,1500 respectively 
i need to optimize the cost
can someone suggest me a generalized way for cont and discrete variables

Comment: Please state the actual optimization problem and the methods your mention. It is doubltful whether the problem is programming-related though.

Comment: the problem is
optimise budjet
subject to 20000<=cost<=30000 and m1=1000,m2=1500,m3=2000  select one method at a time, and the next selection should not be the same one as the immediate previous one     hope i am clear

Comment: It helped a bit, but it doesn't really become clear to me. The objective is to find a finite sequence of the methods where the method is different from its predecessor in order to minimize the total cost, which is to be between 20.000 and 30.000? I don't see a continuous variable here...

Comment: Are you searching for Mixed integer linear programming?